# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Prism.Wpf.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.'

I have reinstalled all of my packages and tried to solve this issue. I don't understand why it is doing this all of the sudden. Any help in this matter will be appreciated.

My Prism application and modules are targeting 4.6 .NET Framework, I also have a .NET Standard 1.3 PCL.

I tried reinstalling VS, reinstalling packages, changing my target framework.

Thank you.

Comment: I reinstalled VS 2017 and it did not help either. There are no build errors, the application launches and the exception throws at the run method of bootstrapper.

Comment: Is Prism compatible with .NET 4.6?

Comment: Have you tried installing prism.wpf as a nudget package

Comment: They were installed from NuGet. I just removed them and reinstalled, this did not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What seemed to work is adding a reference to the System.Runtime library at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll